# Dynamic definitions visuals based on a value in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to put together a quicksight visual in my dashboard, where when a user filters for a particular option in column A, another visual pops up to provide a definition of the corresponding values in column B. Here is an example:

| Customer | Services |
| --- | --- |
| Steven | Pay per month subscription |
| Steven | Gold membership |
| Steven | Legacy member |
| Helen | Pay per month subscription |
| Helen | New member |
| Joe | Pay per month subscription |

I have a list of definitions for the values in the services column.

My dashboard user should be able to filter to the Customer name, and then have the definitions appearing based on the services associated with that customer.

E.g. dashboard user selects Steven. They will then see definition boxes for each of the services that Steven uses. 'Gold membership means that Steven can avoid paying for refunds'.

I tried to do this by switching my dashboard to Freeform, creating text boxes and using 'Hide visual by default' using instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/conditional-rules.html

I then tried to create a conditional rule to only show the visual if a certain option was selected but I could only see the option to show based on parameter, not based on the corresponding value in the services column.